# Failed to fetch binary i386 and amd64 packages

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa, banshee

running Ubuntu 15.10
When I try to apt-get update/upgrade, I get the following error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

as well as the same for colingille/freshlight/ etc (can't post more than two links)

I'm not sure why, any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That PPA was last updated in 2014. [It doesn't have a Wily release](http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

It's dead. Remove it with something like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:banshee-team/ppa
```

Answer (score 1):

This ppa does not have packages for Ubuntu 15.10.

You can remove this PPA using System Settings -> Software & Updates.